# MySQL CASE Statement Returns Different Result in Workbench and Angular

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case, mysql-workbench

I want to get the same result from my PHP API as I get when calling the same SQL query from MySQL Workbench.
I get different results in MySQL Workbench to what I get when calling it from a PHP API when using the CASE statement. Here is the SQL:

```
@row_number:=CASE
                            WHEN @row_number IS NULL THEN
                                1
                            WHEN @dateTime = scrm_lessons_id_lesson THEN 
                                @row_number + 0
                            WHEN @dateTime != scrm_lessons_id_lesson THEN 
                                @row_number + 1
                            END AS lesson_number,
                          
                        @dateTime:= scrm_lessons_id_lesson AS 'LessonID'
```

In Workbench, this gives me the desired result, which is:

```
lesson_number   LessonID
1   17282
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
2   17314
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
3   17349
4   17386
4   17386
4   17386
4   17386
4   17386
5   17416
5   17416
```

i.e, each row with a new LessonID value increments the value of lesson_number.

However, in PHP, the value of lesson_number is always 1 (so it must hit WHEN @row_number IS NULL every time).

The statements are identicle, copy and paste, and run on the same server. One is called from MySQL Workbench coonected to the server remotely, and the other from an API on the server written in PHP.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Please show us the entire query, not just a part of it.

Comment: This is probably due to an issue with the scoping of the variable - `@row_number` is _session variable_ which may not behave as you'd expect when run from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User variables are tricky in MySQL - and they are now officially planed for deprecation in a future version.

If you are running MySL 8.0 (or you can upgrade to that version), just use window functions: `dense_rank()` does exactly what you ask for.

```
select 
    dense_rank() over(order by scrm_lessons_id_lesson) lesson_number, 
    scrm_lessons_id_lesson  lesson_id
from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL *explicitly* warns agains assigning variables and using them in the same expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

You are assigning and using variables in different expressions, so there is no guarantee what order the expressions are evaluated.  Nor even that they are evaluated in the same order in the same query.

Happily, setting variables in `SELECT` statements is now deprecated.  In most cases, you can replace the logic with a window function.

EDIT:

You code seems to describe the function:

```
row_number() over (partition by scrm_lessons_id_lesson order by ?) as lesson_number
```

The `?` is because I don't know the ordering.  It would be based on an `order by` clause used somewhere else in your existing query.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation about why it doesn't work as expected. I don't know which window function to use though. It doesn't seem any of them fit my purpose. Can you be more specific? Or is what I am trying to do not possible with SQL, and should I do it in code either in the API or at the client end?